# Repair wooden footboard rail mount?

Tags: wood-repair

I'm not sure if this is even repairable, got the bedframe second hand, already missing the chunk of wood on the right and the screws in it. I think the crack is getting worse though and I'm not sure how much longer its going to hold up. The metal rods showing has me concerned.

Pictures in gallery.

http://picsurge.com/fWii8H

Let me know if you think I can fix this, and if so, how you would suggest I tackle it.

Comment: There are so many failures in the post assembly that I would be inclined to create a whole new post before attempting to repair and rebuild what is left. The vertical cracks and missing pieces can be repaired, but the crack across the post is more problematic if the repair joint is more of an end joint connection than a side lap one.  In that case the connection could easily fail again when the bed is moved around.

Comment: Just as a general thing, nearly any kind of break can be fixed, although sometimes it will involve glueing in large patches of wood and possibly using quite a bit of filler material afterwards to get a decent surface. Some of the main limiters to what's feasible are the time and cost, and obviously the experience of the person attempting the repair. Here, I think you are looking at replacing a bit chunk of post to make a solid repair in a more traditional manner, although using a good epoxy you could possibly do this just with filler and have it turn out very strong! {contd]

Comment: [contd] As for getting a good Answer here on how you might approach repairing this I think we need a few more pics, one or two of the overall piece and a few of the relevant part but not quite so close so that we can get a better impression of how it relates to the structure, what weight it might have to withstand, that kind of thing — *big* difference in what you can get away with if this needs to take weight every time the bed is used versus being mostly decorative.

Comment: I wish I had time to write a good answer, but all I can do is point you to this hardware: http://www.woodcraft.com/product/127456/bed-rail-fastener.aspx  It's the starting point for your repair.

Comment: Follow-up... are those metal side rails? (They look like they might be.) If so, ignore my link... (Unless by some twist of woodworking sorcery, the receiving plate in the link actually lines up with your existing hooks.) If you can provide the pics requested by @graphus, we might be able to tell if the posts are salvage-able.

Comment: Closed due to broken image that is required to understand the question.